# Joining three 1-D arrays into one array using python

Tags: python, arrays

How to join three arrays u1 = [1,2,3] ; u2 = [4,5,6] ; u3 = [7,8,9] into one array: u = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]?

I am using Python.

Comment: Thank you @BcK.
That doesn´t answer my question though. The result of joining gives me: [5,7,18], it adds Value per Value. What I want is more one array with all the Values in it. 

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the together like this

```
ufull = u1 + u2 + u3
```